# Why do I get this error when trying to obtain back-transformed estimated marginal means using emmeans?

Tags: interaction, linear-model, lsmeans, back-transformation

I am trying to examine the interaction between temperature (factor: 6 levels) and species (factor: 2 levels) in determining the duration of the first larval stage in insects using the following model and the package emmeans:

```
model3<-lm(sqrt(Duration.1st.days)~Temperature*Species, data = first.1)
```

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: sqrt(Duration.1st.days)
                     Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)
Temperature           5 19.2397  3.8479 116.9385 < 2.2e-16
Species               1  2.4146  2.4146  73.3783 < 2.2e-16
Temperature:Species   5  0.7496  0.1499   4.5563 0.0004338
Residuals           625 20.5661  0.0329                   
                       
Temperature         ***
Species             ***
Temperature:Species ***
Residuals              
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am using emmeans in order to compare temperature within species and species within each level of temperature however I would like to get the estimated marginal means and their standard errors on the scale of Duration.1st.days rather than sqrt(Duration.1st days). I have tried the following code but get an error when I run the first line of code. When I run the second the EM means are still on the sqrt scale:

```
Within.species<-emmeans(model3, type = "response", specs = pairwise ~ Temperature|Species)
emmeans:::cld.emmGrid(Within.species$emmeans, Letter = letters, alpha = 0.05)

Note: Use 'contrast(regrid(object), ...)' to obtain contrasts of back-transformed estimates
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what this error means and how I might rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have estimates of $\sqrt{\mu_1}$ and $\sqrt{\mu_2}$, the difference of those estimates is $\sqrt{\mu_1} - \sqrt{\mu_2}$. There is no meaningful way to back-transform that quantity, so for the pairwise differences, the software leaves it on the difference-of-square-root scale, and gives you a message suggesting something else you could do.

I suggest *never* using `pairwise ~ ...` in `emmeans()` because you are asking for two different sets of results, and they are worth thinking about separately. Here are some suggestions to consider:

```
EMM <- emmeans(model3, specs = ~ Temperature|Species)

EMM    # show means on square-root scale
pairs(EMM)    # pairwise differences on square-root scale
confint(EMM, type = "response")    # means on response scale

# If you want comparisons on the response scale, the message suggests...
regrid(EMM)    # convert to response scale and create a whole new grid of means
               # Display will be the same as above, but internal structure differs
pairs(regrid(EMM))   # pairwise differences on response scale
cld(regrid(EMM))     # compact letter display
```

Read the [vignette on transformations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html) for more discussion.

For lots of reasons, I don't think much of CLDs; the main reason is that they display what you *can't* show rather than what you *can*. I'd suggest [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/re-engineering-clds.html) as well.

Comment: Is it important when the back-transformation takes place? If my understanding is correct, in the first case, the statistical tests to determine significant pairwise differences are conducted using the data on the sqrt scale and, in the second case, the tests use the date on the original scale. My data was only sqrt transformed to improve residual normality so the data isn't really of use to me in this scale. In this case, which approach would you recommend?

Comment: YES. Please note in the vignette I linked, there is a section titled "Timing is Everything."

Comment: I think the tests of differences should be on the sqrt scale. Maybe you're not interested in those, but that's the scale on which the tests are more valid, because that makes the errors more normal/homogeneous. And that's why the default is to test things on the sqrt scale, not on the re-gridded scale. But if you want to see *estimates* of the differences of response means, re-gridding is the only way you can get them.